# PHP MySQLi possible issue with escaped parameter in escaped statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is something I have been trying to figure out for a bit, it is the most simplest of queries that does not seem to want to work for me (only in php mysqli, works in console sql)

First I am using a prepared statement, merely looking for a match on a specialized id (from another service) to update the relation to use my primary key for easier searching on my end.

The query is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT id 
          FROM {$this->config->dbprefix}{$table} 
          WHERE sf_id = ? 
          LIMIT 1";
```

*I use this as one line, I split it up for better readability here*

I then check that the prepare statement is valid (I do this in multiple places and it works everywhere else.

```
if(!($ret = $this->dbo->prepare($query))){
  //handle error, this part is never called
}else{
  //everything is fine, code in here is below
}
```

Up to here everything seems fine. Checking table and prefix manually shows they are working and referencing the proper table.

```
$ret->bind_param('s',$id);
$ret->execute();
$ret->bind_result($retId);
$ret->fetch();
$count = $ret->num_rows;
```

The problem is here, the query always returns 0 for the num_rows. Checking the query manually and trying it in console returns 1 result as it should. So far with it being such a simple query I just cannot wrap my head around why it would work elsewhere, but not here. I am sure this is the proper way to build it (I have many other queries structured similar).

Is there any kind of confusion I may be experiencing? Something easy to miss that could cause a query like this to not return results?

EDIT:
I have attempted further error handling, and trying an if test on execute does not trigger an error, though I will try more.

To expand I have a raw output of the `$query` variable and the `id` variable. By combining them and manually attempting the query in console I get the proper result. My thoughts are on somehow the prepare statement is escaping, causing the string variable `$id` to not properly match. Though that is just speculation.

Comment: You should add some error handling here because it's not just the `prepare` statement that can produce errors.

Comment: Is the `sf_id` `varchar` in your database or an `int`? When you check the query manually and it works, what is your syntax for that?

Comment: I have some, num_rows returns 0, meaning no results. So according to the prepare showing as the table and columns are valid, and that the query executes and returns nothing that there is possibly an error with the $id is the only logical thing I can see. `sf_id` is `varchar` and I had the query output, replacing the ? with the actual id as returned by the same function, and in console it returns 1 result properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `store_result()` before trying to access `num_rows`.  Without it, the statement handle does not know how many rows are in the result set.

```
$ret->bind_param('s',$id);
$ret->execute();
$ret->bind_result($retId);
$ret->store_result();
$count = $ret->num_rows;
// perhaps add error handling based on number of rows here
$ret->fetch();
```

Comment: Ah, I was under the assumption that store result was to get the result without binding, and fetch did the same thing but with a bind.